# Modifying "Possible duplicate:" links

Tags: discussion, editing, duplicates, closed-questions

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/13996/revisions) I found out that there's a better duplicate than the one mentioned in 
"**Possible duplicate:**" automatically added text. I decided to edit the question and add the other link.

Now I'm not sure if this was a good idea. Whence I would like to know what is the opinion of other people on adding possible duplicated to the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've done this before.  My guidelines are:

1. Keep the original possible duplicate.  That was, after all, the majority view.  If I disagree with this then I'd want to discuss it first (here or in chat).
2. Make the plurality clear: "Possible duplicate **s**" and put them in a list.

Other than that, this is a good idea so long as it really is a possible duplicate and not just a "you might also want to see".  For the latter then I'd put it in a comment (whereupon it also turns up in the "Linked" list).

After all, so long as it is a reasonable duplicate then you are *adding* value so this is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Re “That was, after all, the majority view”: it’s the majority view among the first five closevoters, but that’s a pretty small sample size.